# Why is the Query from getInitialProps empty?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, next.js, server-side-rendering

I want to fetch some data using query parameters on the server for a page.

However, my query is empty inside getInitialProps when rendered through server. Why could this be happening?

Moreover, I have noticed this only happens in production server and not in the dev or prod env on my local.

Here's some code

```
import React from 'react';

import Config from 'component/Config';

import { withAuthSync } from 'util/auth';
import apiUrl from 'util/apiUrl';

function ResourceConfigPage({ data }) {
  return <Config data={data} />;
}

ResourceConfigPage.getInitialProps = async ctx => {
  const { resourceId } = ctx.query;
  try {
    const response = await fetch(`${apiUrl}/resource/config?resourceId=${resourceId}`, {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      }
    });
    if (response.ok) {
      const data = await response.json();
      return { data };
    }
  }
  return {};
};

export default withAuthSync(ResourceConfigPage);
```

My next app uses a custom express server and here's how it looks.

```
const express = require('express');
const next = require('next');
const compression = require('compression');

const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';
const app = next({ dev });
const handle = app.getRequestHandler();

app
  .prepare()
  .then(() => {
    const server = express();
    app.setAssetPrefix(dev ? '' : 'https://example.com');
    server.use(compression());

    server.get('/healthcheck', (req, res) => {
      res.status(200).json({});
    });
    server.get('/', (req, res) => {
      if (req.cookies.sessionId) {
        res.redirect('/dashboard');
      }
      res.redirect('/login');
    });

    server.get('*', (req, res) => {
      return handle(req, res);
    });
    server.listen(3000, err => {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log('> Ready on http://localhost:3000');
    });
  })
  .catch(ex => {
    console.error(ex.stack);
    process.exit(1);
  });
```

Comment: check ur `resourceId` value on server

Comment: the query object is empty when server rendered, but works on client render.

Comment: can u create a jsfiddle its really hard to find ur problem this way.
note please check the network tab of your browser and see if it hit the proper link or it sents the value u need to send

Comment: Do you have a custom express server?

Comment: @felixmosh Yes I do.

Comment: So probably You are not passing the 3rd parameter to app.render, check this example https://github.com/zeit/next.js/blob/canary/examples/custom-server-express/server.js#L13

Comment: @felixmosh My server doesn't really render a lot since upgrading to next 9. It has some redirection logic and is used for compression and asset prefixing. 
I've added a snippet of how it looks in the question.

Comment: I see, did you have tried to debug it?